# Drag and Drop - change background on condition

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

My aim is a little game, where statements can be **dragged and dropped** onto **two different areas**. One is correct, one isn't. Depending on that I would like to change the **backgroundcolor**. I am struggling with defining the conditions.

list item 1 in box 1 - green / list item 1 in box 2 - red, and vice versa

Example: http://codepen.io/TheRed/pen/uGKom
Many thanks!

HTML

```
 <div id="div1"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Box 1</div>
 <div id="div2"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Box 2</div>
 <p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" name="green">Statement 1</p>
 <p id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" name="red">Statement 2</p>
```

CSS

```
 #div1 {height:50px; width:400px; border:2px solid black;}
 #div2 {height:50px; width:400px; border:2px solid black; margin-top: 20px }
  p {font-weight:bold; width:200px;}
```

and JS:

```
   function allowDrop(ev)
    {
    ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev)
    {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

 function drop(ev)
    {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

        if(document.getElementById(data).id == 'drag1'){             
    document.getElementById('div1').style.background = 'green'; 
        }
        else if(document.getElementById(data).id == 'drag2'){   
      document.getElementById('div2').style.background = 'red';
        }

        }
```

Comment: where is drag implementation?

Comment: copy and paste, sorry, added the implementation, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in this way, I have used [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).
every draggable and droppable element has a `data-target` that should match to get the green background

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4JCN/2/)**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
          $('.droppable[data-target="' + ui.draggable.attr('data-target') + '"]').removeClass('backgroundRed').removeClass('backgroundGreen');
          if (ui.draggable.attr("data-target")==$(this).attr("data-target")){
               $( this ).removeClass("backgroundRed").addClass( "backgroundGreen" );         
          }
          else{

               $( this ).removeClass("backgroundGreen").addClass( "backgroundRed" );

      }
      }});
  });
```

css

```
.backgroundGreen{
    background:green!important;
}
.backgroundRed{
    background:red!important;
}
.backgroundGray{
    background:#cdcdcd!important;;
}
```

html

```
<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content draggable" data-target="1">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable1" class="ui-widget-header droppable" data-target="1">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content draggable" data-target="2">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable2" class="ui-widget-header droppable" data-target="2">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, its working well. One additional question: If I drag my answer away from the element, the color stays the same. What would be the best approach to remove the color, once the item has been dragged away? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @TheRed I've edited my answer to achieve your question. There was a missing `"`. Let me know if works now

Comment: It works now for the green background, not yet for the misplaced items/the red background. Thank you very much for your effort.